# Need to replicate this Bar plot in Tableau

Tags: visualization, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I saw this dashboard that i really liked, and i wanted to replicate. It is a Barplot of highest payed Players(this doesnt matter i guess), but the way the bars are shown is really interesting.

[image]

Here is the link to the original Visualization:

https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/justindavis/viz/NBARookies_15612454498920/NBARookies

just click on the toggle button above to switch to this visual.

Like i said if anybody has an idea that woukd be my appreciated, thanks.

Tried changing some basic stuff, didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out a nice example view.

One of the great things about Tableau Public is that most authors allow you to download their workbooks, so you can deconstruct some viz you like, learn how it works and apply those methods to your own visualizations. Its a great way to learn and get to the point where you can answer your own questions. Give it a shot.

In this case, the author created what's called a Unit Chart. He did that using a Shape mark type instead of bars. To do that he provided a custom shape icon. Tableau's help documentation explains how to create custom shapes and where to place them.

Often in a unit chart, each individual mark represents something specific, like one game or one season. In those cases, you can have a tooltip show more detail for each mark when the user hovers on it. But in this case, the number of colored marks just depend on the 4 year value. So he's just using a unit chart as an alternative way to present a bar chart. Its very attractive and interesting, but functionally equivalent to a bar chart. That's also a common use for a unit chart.

FWIW, there is a variation on this chart that places the shapes in some rectangular grid - often to show percentages as an alternative to a pie chart. Those grids of squares are usually called waffle charts.